# Given a list of slices, how do I split a sequence by them?

Tags: python

#### Given a list of slices, how do I separate a sequence based on them?

I have long amino-acid strings that I would like to split based on start-stop values in a list. An example is probably the most clear way of explaining it:

```
str = "MSEPAGDVRQNPCGSKAC"
split_points = [[1,3], [7,10], [12,13]]

output >> ['M', '(SEP)', 'AGD', '(VRQN)', 'P', '(CG)', 'SKAC']
```

The extra parentheses are to show which elements were selected from the split_points list. I don't expect the start-stop points to ever overlap.

I have a bunch of ideas that would work, but seem terribly inefficient (code-length wise), and it seems like there must be a nice pythonic way of doing this.

Comment: This is a really good question, and is not limited to strings.

Comment: one thing to note about the sample code, don't use str as a variable in python.  That's the name of the built-in class.  And shadowing built-ins almost always will bite you later.

Comment: `str` is a *really* bad name here, as I was confused by the solutions that appeared to be invoking the str built-in instead of slicing the str variable.  Unfortunately, you can't edit it now, as then the posted answers would be even *more* confusing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Strange way to split strings you have there:

```
def splitter( s, points ):
    c = 0
    for x,y in points:
        yield s[c:x]
        yield "(%s)" % s[x:y+1]
        c=y+1
    yield s[c:]

print list(splitter(str, split_points))
# => ['M', '(SEP)', 'AGD', '(VRQN)', 'P', '(CG)', 'SKAC']

# if some start and endpoints are the same remove empty strings.
print list(x for x in splitter(str, split_points) if x != '')
```

Comment: This one wins in speed, but I'm over vote limit. I honestly think a version of this in C should get folded into itertools. You should submit a patch.

Comment: @Jed, I'm actually clocking his in at ~ 100ms slower than the one have.  Although his use of a generator is elegant.

Comment: Ack! I accidently voted this down and it won't let me change it now.  If anyone is able to fix this please do.

Comment: @Bryan: `THC4k [5.5428318977355957, 5.4677660465240479, 5.4681069850921631]
Bryan [6.1738638877868652, 6.0337700843811035, 5.9942479133605957]`, yours is slightly slower...not sure what construct you're using (that's 1,000,000 runs)

Comment: @Bryan - chill, man, don't go all Cathy on us - just click the down triangle again.

Comment: The `scanString` method of pyparsing does similar splitting, yielding each matched fragment from within a body of text.  Pyparsing's `transformString` method wraps `scanString` almost exactly like this generator: emitting the intervening text, then the parsed/modified text for each match; then the trailing text if any; and then finally joining the whole thing back to a single string.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution for you. to grab each of the sets specified by the point.

```
In[4]:  str[p[0]:p[1]+1] for p in split_points]
Out[4]: ['SEP', 'VRQN', 'CG']
```

To get the parenthesis:

```
In[5]:  ['(' + str[p[0]:p[1]+1] + ')' for p in split_points]
Out[5]: ['(SEP)', '(VRQN)', '(CG)']
```

Here is the cleaner way of doing it to do the whole deal:

```
results = []

for i in range(len(split_points)):
    start, stop = split_points[i]
    stop += 1

    last_stop = split_points[i-1][1] + 1 if i > 0 else 0

    results.append(string[last_stop:start])        
    results.append('(' + string[start:stop] + ')')

results.append(string[split_points[-1][1]+1:])
```

**All of the below solutions are bad, and more for fun than anything else, do not use them!**

This more of a WTF solution, but I figured I'd post it since it was asked for in comments:

```
split_points = [(x, y+1) for x, y in split_points]
split_points = [((split_points[i-1][1] if i > 0 else 0, p[0]), p) for i, p in zip(range(len(split_points)), split_points)]
results = [string[n[0]:n[1]] + '\n(' + string[m[0]:m[1]] + ')' for n, m in split_points] + [string[split_points[-1][1][1]:]]
results = '\n'.join(results).split()
```

still trying to figure out the one liner, here's a two:

```
split_points = [((split_points[i-1][1]+1 if i > 0 else 0, p[0]), (p[0], p[1]+1)) for i, p in zip(range(len(split_points)), split_points)]
print '\n'.join([string[n[0]:n[1]] + '\n(' + string[m[0]:m[1]] + ')' for n, m in split_points] + [string[split_points[-1][1][1]:]]).split()
```

And the one liner that should never be used:

```
print '\n'.join([string[n[0]:n[1]] + '\n(' + string[m[0]:m[1]] + ')' for n, m in (((split_points[i-1][1]+1 if i > 0 else 0, p[0]), (p[0], p[1]+1)) for i, p in zip(range(len(split_points)), split_points))] + [string[split_points[-1][1]:]]).split()
```

Comment: The output is missing the parts between the split points.  If you get that with a list comprehension, my hat is off to you.

Comment: Heh, maybe the 5-liner answers ARE the pythonic way :)

Comment: Well my longer solution takes about 660ms to do 100k iterations locally.  Where my one line solution takes 1.17s to do 100k  So the unrolled version there is definitely faster

Comment: @latentflip: most assuredly, as the the 1-liners seem more perlific to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that will work.

```
result = []
last_end = 0
for sp in split_points:
  result.append(str[last_end:sp[0]])
  result.append('(' + str[sp[0]:sp[1]+1] + ')')
  last_end = sp[1]+1
result.append(str[last_end:])

print result
```

If you just want the parts in the parenthesis it becomes a little simpler:

```
result = [str[sp[0]:sp[1]+1] for sp in split_points]
```

Comment: I think you need last_end=sp[1]+1, and then a result.append(str[last_end:]) after the for loop. But otherwise that works. I thought it might be doable with list comprehensions, but maybe it would overly complex.

Comment: Oh yeah, I borked up the edge conditions for the non-selected elements. Thanks for the fix.

Comment: The reason THC4k's answer is winning is because of the usage of a generator (even though you did something roughly similar).  For a basic iterator, i.e., `for slice in jblocksom(A, B):`, it's more memory-efficient to yield each piece instead of building a list and returning it.  That's the only reason yours isn't getting upvoted, as the logic is almost exactly the same.

Comment: @JedSmith Good to know about memory efficiency, I wouldn't have figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not for elegance, but just because I can do it in a oneliner :)

```
>>> reduce(lambda a,ij:a[:-1]+[str[a[-1]:ij[0]],'('+str[ij[0]:ij[1]+1]+')',
            ij[1]], split_points, [0])[:-1] + [str[split_points[-1][-1]+1:]]

['M', '(SEP)', 'PAGD', '(VRQN)', 'NP', '(CG)', 'SKAC']
```

Maybe you like it. Here some explanation:

In your question you pass one set of slices, and implicitly you want to have the complement set of slices as well (to generate the un-parenthesized [is that English?] slices). So basically, each slice [i,j] lacks the previous j. e.g. [7,10] lacks the 3 and [1,3] lacks the 0.

`reduce` processes lists and at each step passes *the output so far* (`a`) plus the *next input element* (`ij`). The trick is that apart from producing the plain output, we add each time an extra variable --- a sort of memory --- which is in the next step retrieved in `a[-1]`. In this particular example we store the last j value, and hence at all times we have the full information to provide both the unparenthesized and the parenthesized substring.

Finally, the memory is stripped with [:-1] and replaced by the remainder of the original str in `[str[split_points[-1][-1]+1:]]`.

Comment: I'm not sure which one's more barbarous, your one liner or mine.

Comment: I like it, not that I can particularly follow it (lacking practice in lambda functions and reduce()).

Comment: It's entertaining, but the unrolled one on mine is the better of my solutions, heh.

Comment: @Bryan: You will achieve greatness today.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that converts your split_points to regular string slices and then prints out the appropriate slices:

```
str = "MSEPAGDVRQNPCGSKAC"
split_points = [[1, 3], [7, 10], [12, 13]]

adjust = [s for sp in [[x, y + 1] for x, y in split_points] for s in sp]
zipped = zip([None] + adjust, adjust + [None])

out = [('(%s)' if i % 2 else '%s') % str[x:y] for i, (x, y) in
       enumerate(zipped)]

print out

>>> ['M', '(SEP)', 'AGD', '(VRQN)', 'P', '(CG)', 'SKAC']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> str = "MSEPAGDVRQNPCGSKAC"
>>> split_points = [[1,3], [7,10], [12,13]]
>>>
>>> all_points = sum(split_points, [0]) + [len(str)-1]
>>> map(lambda i,j: str[i:j+1], all_points[:-1], all_points[1:])
['MS', 'SEP', 'PAGDV', 'VRQN', 'NPC', 'CG', 'GSKAC']
>>>
>>> str_out = map(lambda i,j: str[i:j+1], all_points[:-1:2], all_points[1::2])
>>> str_in = map(lambda i,j: str[i:j+1], all_points[1:-1:2], all_points[2::2])
>>> sum(map(list, zip(['(%s)' % s for s in str_in], str_out[1:])), [str_out[0]])
['MS', '(SEP)', 'PAGDV', '(VRQN)', 'NPC', '(CG)', 'GSKAC']
```